# Failed to get hold of *ngFor looped <md-option> elements using @ViewChildren

Tags: angular

I would like to select for the list of  elements in order to focus one of them at will given a value of an option.

select.component.template:

```
<md-select
        [formControl]="selectFormControl"
        (click)="detectKeys()"
        [required]="isRequired"
        [disabled]="isDisabled"
        [attr.role]="'listbox'"
        [attr.aria-labelledby]="placeholder"
        placeholder="placeholder">
  <md-option #selectBox *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">  
    {{option.description}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

select.component.ts:

```
export class UiSelectComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    ....
    @Input() options: Object[];
    @ViewChildren('selectBox') selects: QueryList<any>;
    ....
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.selects.length); // comes up empty results
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could think of putting subscription over `QueryList` of `selectBox`

```
this.selects.changes.subscribe((option: QueryList <any>) => {
   console.log(option);
});
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you. Last question: the type `<any>` for `QueryList`, is that right?

Comment: @kyw over here yes, When it comes to `component`, it would component `Type`